# Print a big integer with punctions with Python3 string formatting mini-language

Tags: python, python-3.x, number-formatting

I want a point after each three digits in a big number (e.g. `4.100.200.300`).

```
>>> x = 4100200300
>>> print('{}'.format(x))
4100200300
```

This question is specific to Pythons string formatting mini-language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's only one available thousands separator.

> The `','` option signals the use of a comma for a thousands separator.

([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language))

Example:

```
'{:,}'.format(x) # 4,100,200,300
```

If you need to use a dot as a thousand separator, consider replacing commas with `'.'` or setting the locale (*LC_NUMERIC* category) appropriately.

You could use [this](http://lh.2xlibre.net/values/thousands_sep/) list to find the right locale. Note that you'll have to use the `n` integer presentation type for locale-aware formatting:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE') # or da_DK, or lt_LT, or mn_MN, or ...
'{:n}'.format(x) # 4.100.200.300
```

In my opinion, the former approach is much simpler:

```
'{:,}'.format(x).replace(',', '.') # 4.100.200.300
```

or

```
format(x, ',').replace(',', '.') # 4.100.200.300
```